# "OR" clause in Outlook 2007 Search Folders - Folder Composition

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2007

Is it possible to specify a Search Folder in Outlook 2007 that will use an OR rule ("any") instead of an AND rule ("and")?

In particular, I have a search folder named A and another named B; I want a search folder named AB that will have all the messages that are in either A or B, or both.

When I specify AB with the rules "In Folder is A exactly" and "In Folder is B exactly", I get an empty folder, possibly because at the moment no messages are in both.

Is the workaround to rename "A" to "A workaround" and "B" to "B workaround" and then specify "AB" with the rule "In Folder contains workaround"?  Urggh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the "In Folder" attribute is not talking about search folders, but actual inbox/pst folders...  A search folder is not considered a folder in this regard (it's just a set of search conditions).

So, there are two solutions:

1. If you meant that FolderA and FolderB are inbox folders, then you simply select those folders in the "Mail from these folders will be included..." browse dialog.
2. If FolderA and FolderB actually are search folders, then you'd have to analyze the criteria for these folders and combine them.  If this is not possible because they are keying on different fields (different fields are considered AND), then you might try [this outlook-tip](http://www.outlook-tips.net/archives/2004/20040927.htm) , which references an MS-KB activating QueryBuilder (which allows complex and/or).

Comment: cool, thanks a lot for the hint on outlook QueryBuilder!