# Outlook 2007 search folders with address wildcards and "OR" conditions?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, search

How can I create a search folder with addresses that are not in my address book?

For example, I'd like to have a "SomeCo" search folder, that contains the search query "from:someco OR to:someco"

Under the Search Folder Criteria, it seems all I can do is create a list of specific names from my address book.

Also if I put names in "From" and "To", it appears the relation is always "AND". It is the same in Advanced Find. All the items in the list are AND conditions. How are OR conditions accomplished?  [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/44586/or-clause-in-outlook-2007-search-folders-folder-composition) was previoulsy asked, but it was more of a special case.

Answer (score 1):

Querybuilder is the solution. I'm puzzled why Microsoft disables this capability by default.
See [this article](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/outlook-create-powerful-search-folders-with-query-builder/) as referenced in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/346295/outlook-search-folder-how-to-filter-messages-that-have-one-category-but-dont).